# Strsplit within cell array and concatenate

Tags: string, matlab, cell-array

I have a cell array of strings. It is in two columns. The first column contains whitespace, and I want to split it into multiple columns based on the whitespace. The second column has line breaks I want to remove.

The following function ALMOST gives me what I want:

```
col1 = arrayfun(@(r) [strsplit(allpacks{r,1})],1:rows,'Uni',0).';
col2 = arrayfun(@(r) regexprep(allpacks{r,2},'[\n\r\f]+',''),1:rows,'Uni',0).';
allpacks = [col1, col2];
```

col2 is perfect, exactly what I want.

col1, however, is a (rows x 1) cell array of cells, with each cell being a 1x21 cell array of strings. I want col1 to actually be a (rows x 21) cell array of strings. I feel I'm really close, but nothing I've tried works. How can I get what I want here?

Per comment, here is some Example Data from Column 1:

```
  1 2015-09-03 08:02:15.067342000 0.000000000 0.000000000   172.24.2.2 -> 172.24.2.34  Modbus/TCP 64    query: trans: 12289; unit:  42, func:   4: Read Input Registers
```

I want each "word" in this string to be it's own column in the cell array. Note there are 20 "words" but it comes out to 21 because the initial space ends up getting its own column from strsplit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should do what you want:

```
%// example data
rows = 5;
col1 = repmat({num2cell(1:26)},rows,1)
col2 = num2cell(1:rows).' %'

%// output
allpacks = [vertcat(col1{:}), col2];
```

Comment: I don't understand how this code applies to what I'm trying to do. It creates an example cell array with doubles. I'm using strings, so num2cell does not apply to what I'm doing.

Comment: @Trashman No, but the last line does. You can use your `col1` and `col2` with the last line and see if it works for you.

Comment: "I see" said the blind man to the deaf dog. Thank you for your help.